# Error in Postgis SQL statement for OSM data

Tags: postgresql, postgis, openstreetmap, where-clause

I am trying to select a particular value in the OSM polygon data using DB Manager in QGIS that is connected to the PostGIS database. When I type

```
SELECT * 
FROM planet_osm_polygon 
WHERE landuse is not null
```

This SQL statement works. It gives me all the rows that has the landuse values.

However, if I replace `landuse` with `natural` (which is another column name) it gives me an error message. I used another column name for example, `leisure`. I get the query result.

I am not sure why I can't use `natural` column heading name. Any clue to solve this error will be appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

`natural` is a [reserved keyword](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/sql-keywords-appendix.html), so you need to enclose it is double quotes:

```sql
SELECT * FROM osm_polygons WHERE "natural" is not null;
```

PS: the same is true if you have a semicolon in the column name:

```sql
SELECT * FROM osm_polygons WHERE "addr:housenumber" is not null;
```